# will my pilot's license be considered "Frozen ATPL"?

Tags: pilot-certification

I am a CPL(A) commercial pilot license holder with MEP and IR ratings.  This CPL(A) has been issued by an ICAO Member State under the rules of Annex 1 to the Chicago Convention.  This country is not a member of EASA and does not operate under the EASA Part FCL rules.
I want to get a job in Kazakhstan, where EASA standards are being actively implemented.  Now for employment in Kazakhstan you need to have "Frozen ATPL".
According to Annex 1 to the Chicago Convention, there is a procedure for a state to give effect to a certificate issued in another state (this process is called validation).  In Kazakhstan, such a procedure exists and has been introduced at the legislative level.  The "Rules for the Recognition of Foreign Licenses" approved in Kazakhstan stipulate that Kazakhstan recognizes licenses if they comply with the standards set forth in Annex 1 to the Chicago Convention, and that if recognized, the license will be equivalent to the Kazakh CPL(A).
It turns out that after going through the recognition (validation) procedure, I will receive a Certificate of recognition of my license and it will be fully equivalent to the Kazakh CPL (A).

Next, I want to prepare and pass 14 ATPL theoretical exams in Kazakhstan and receive a certificate of successful completion.

As a result, I will have such a set of documents:

1. certificate of recognition of my CPL(A) with qualification marks "MEP" and "IR"
2. Actually my license is CPL(A) MEP/IR
3. Certificate of passing 14 ATPL exams

Please tell me, will this set of documents be called "Frozen ATPL" in this case?

THANK YOU FOR FEEDBACK